# Using $_POST variables in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I have been trying to work out prepared statements, and using $_POST variables in it, but nothing I've seen online seems to work. I know that questions are meant to show proper research, but I can't find anything that matches this question online. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pass');
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$key = md5(microtime().rand());
try {
  $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO requests (formname, formemail, formphone, formpostcode, formitem, formnotes, formbudget, formdatefor, currentdate, deletekey, resolved, deleted)
    VALUES (:name, :email, :phone, :postcode, :item, :notes, :budget, :datefor, :curentdate, :key, '0', '0')");

  $params = array_intersect_key($_POST, array('name', 'email', 'phone', 'postcode', 'item', 'notes', 'budget', 'datefor', 'currentdate', 'key'));
  $query->execute($params);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  die("An error occurred, contact the site administrator.");
}
```

Comment: You didn't include an error message in your question.

Comment: Aren't you just missing ':' in front of your bind parameters?

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's because I don't get an error message.

Comment: `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

Comment: when you face strange insert errors, you can start by adding one filed each time, until you see if there is anything wrong there. when you have bunch of fields, it's hard to say where and what could go wrong ...

Comment: Ok, here is the error I got in the log file: "AH01215: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $params = array_intersect_key($_POST, array('name', 'email', 'phone', 'postcode', 'item', 'notes', 'budget', 'date for', 'currentdate', 'key'));
> ```

The array on the right has the ***keys*** `0`, `1`, `2` etc. The `$_POST` array has the keys `name`, `email` etc (I assume). Their intersection is nothing. `array_intersect_key` intersects on the ***keys*** of both arrays, not on the keys of one and the values of the other.

You want:

```
$params = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(array('name', ...)));
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This would have been easy to figure out if you had tried `var_dump($params)`.

You should still error check here though, since nothing guarantees that `$_POST` will contain all values you're expecting, in which case you'll trigger a PDO error about missing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There are nowhere in your $_POST array keys 'currentdate', 'key', I believe.

Comment: Ok, I've removed them, I'll add them in later. But it's still not working. The error log shows "AH01215: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"